# Change the color of placeholder in digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc, placeholder, jquery-mask

I'm using [digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) for contact numbers. Is it possible to use different color for placeholders?

```
 $(".countryCode").mask("00999999", { placeholder: "-", autoclear: false });
```

update: I don't want to use `keyup`, since maybe the value has generated by server side code.

Comment: try to take a look to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::placeholder)

Comment: It's not supportable in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

Would you want it in css? that would be

```
.countryCode::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

this piece of code works for Chrome and it should also work for Opera and Safari

Here's a working
[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/13tadn2p/2/)